# Arduino Uno programed from a Nvidia Jetson tx2

Tags: serial, programming

I'm trying to program my Arduino Uno with a Jetson tx2 and get the error

```
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
```

The serial port is set to /dev/ttyS0

dmesg when the Arduino is plugged in returns

```
[78222.855639] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 60
[78224.468387] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 61 using xhci-tegra
[78224.605794] usb 1-1: feature bit otg_vbus_off set
[78224.610575] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0043
[78224.617365] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
[78224.624750] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
[78224.630502] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 55739323237351306122
[78224.636529] usb 1-1: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 1024 microframes, ep desc says 2040 microframes
[78224.646057] xhci-tegra 3530000.xhci: tegra_xhci_mbox_work mailbox command 6
```

lsusb returns

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 054: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 065: ID 2341:0043 Arduino SA Uno R3 (CDC ACM)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Did you notice that the log doesn't mention a device file?

Comment: I did not what does that mean I have to do

Answer (score 1):

The version of the Arduino IDE contained in the Jetson repositories is buggy on the Jetson TX2 with Jetpack 3.2+ and the Arduino IDE in the repository is rather old.  Instead, try the beta related to [Github Issue #7302](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/7302).  This beta should work with the Jetson and other aarch64 platforms.  Many thanks to the wonderful people working to support this platform.

### Steps

After downloading and unpackaging the build, perform the following steps:

```
#Install the OpenJDK Dependencies
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jdk

#Remove the Packaged Java Folder
cd ${PATH}/arduino-PR-beta1.9-BUILD-69
sudo rm -r java

#Add armhf Architecture to Package Manager
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:armhf libstdc++6:armhf

#Install the Arduino IDE
sudo ./install.sh
sudo ./arduino-linux-setup.sh

#Reboot
```

### Notes

- The script `arduino-linux-setup.sh` handles the permissions for the IDE to talk to ttyACM0, updates the udev rules, and removes the pesky Modem Manger.
- The armhf packages are necessay to prevent ctags from crashing.
- If you are still having issues with CDC/ACM, install the module using the scripts from [JetsonHacks](https://www.jetsonhacks.com/2017/11/19/install-ttyacm-module-nvidia-jetson-tx-development-kits/)

Answer (score 0):

The device *should* be `/dev/ttyACM0`, *not* `/dev/ttyS0`.

Since it doesn't provide you with that device it rather looks like it doesn't have the CDC/ACM device drivers installed or loaded.

Depending on what distribution of Linux you're running on there you may need to install additional packages (you certainly do for OpenWRT, but I have no clue what that device is you're using or what it's running).

Comment: Jetson's run Ubuntu. I have found posts saying it should show up as /dev/ttyUSB0, but I don't know how to have it do so.

Comment: Maybe ask on a site where someone knows what one of these Jetson things is. CDC/ACM, which is what the Arudino uses, will be /dev/ttyACM0. It's only /dev/ttyUSB0 for FT232 or other similar custom UART interfaces (CH340G, etc).

Answer (score 0):

When you built your Jenson kernel, did you enable the CDC/ACM driver using menuconfig?

From [Arduino Playground](https://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/Linux):

> If you configured your own kernel, the driver is either under "Device
>   Drivers => USB Support => USB Serial Converter Support => USB FTDI
>   Single Port Serial Driver" or "Device Drivers => USB Support => USB
>   Modem (CDC ACM) support". Select [Y], to have it "built in" to the
>   kernel or [M] to have it built as a module.

I'm not familiar with Arduino and whether it would show up as `/dev/ttyUSB0` or `/dev/ttyACM0` per @Majenko.